# Kivy Python Recycleview Update on Buttonpress

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make the recycleview in my code visible after pressing the Update Button. After pressing this Button again the list should update with the new data given. The problem is that the Update Button doesn't work that way.

I made the code as easy to read as possible so hopefully anybody sees the problem without too much amount of time needed.

If I write the data directly at startup I see some output, so I guess the main problem is that recycleview isn't updating (which I read a lot about but I cannot figure it out).

main py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def update(self):
        Scanner.change_number(self)


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print ("Init RV done")

        # By directly writing the Data everything is fine
        # name_list = ['adam', 'peter', 'christine', 'lisa']
        # number_list = ['1923', '1924', '1925', '1929']
        # RV.data = [{'name': name_list[x], 'number': number_list[x]} for x in range(4)]

    def update_list(self, name_list, number_list):
        # this part is not working
        print("Updating...")
        self.data = [{'name': name_list[x], 'number': number_list[x]} for x in range(4)]
        #self.parent.refresh_from_data(self)


class Scanner():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Scanner Init Done")

    def change_number(self):
        # here excluded is some magic function generating numbers
        name_list = ['adam', 'peter', 'christine', 'lisa']
        number_list = ['1923', '1924', '1925', '1929']
        RV.update_list(self, name_list, number_list)


class ScreenManagerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
        root.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='SecondScreen'))
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreenManagerApp().run()
```

test.kv:

```
<EachItem@BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    name: []
    number: []

    GridLayout:
        rows:1
        cols:2
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                id: Row1
                text: str(" ".join(root.name))
                mipmap: True
            Label:
                id: Row2
                text: str(" ".join(root.number))
                mipmap: True


<RV>:
    id: Hostlist
    bar_width: 20
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: 120
    viewclass: 'EachItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        padding: 10, 0, 10, 0
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        default_size: None, 40
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 3

<MainScreen>:
    rows: 1
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 3
        spacing: 10
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, .1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        FloatLayout:
            height: "100"
            size_hint_y: None
            Button:
                text: "Update"
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "y":0}
                on_press: root.update()
        BoxLayout:
            height: "50"
            size_hint_y: None
            GridLayout:
                padding: 10, 0, 10, 0
                rows:1
                cols:4
                Label:
                    text: "Row1"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                Label:
                    text: "Row2"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

        RV

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: 'Previous screen'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 150, 50
            on_release: root.manager.current = root.manager.previous()
```

Comment: Everywhere that you use `SomeClassName.method(self)` (like `RV.update_list(self, name_list, number_list)` and `Scanner.change_number(self)`), you need to replace the class name with the current instance of that class, and eliminate the `self` argument. (Note that `Scanner().change_number()` is also incorrect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some odd class construction, but assuming that is a result of other considerations, you can make it work by making a few changes. Since I don't see any instance of `Scanner`, you can change the `change_number()` method to a static method (so you don't need an instance) like this:

```
class Scanner():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Scanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Scanner Init Done")

    @staticmethod
    def change_number():
        # here excluded is some magic function generating numbers
        name_list = ['adam', 'peter', 'christine', 'lisa']
        number_list = ['1923', '1924', '1925', '1929']
        App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('MainScreen').ids.rv.update_list(name_list, number_list)
```

The last line above is just a way to get the instance of `RV` that is in your display, but it requires setting the `id` of your `RV` in the `<MainScreen>` rule of your 'kv' file:

```
    RV:
        id: rv
```

Note that the `id` in:

```
<RV>:
    id: Hostlist
```

is not useful.

And the `MainScreen` class changes slightly to call the new static method:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):

    def update(self):
        Scanner.change_number()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with a static method before but your last line in change_number and the misconfig in the kv file where the exact two things that where the problem.